# Android RecyclerView Pagination - How to add items to the top of RecyclerView properly?

Tags: android, pagination, android-recyclerview

I have solved the problem of pagination when scrolling down in a `RecyclerView`, but am not able to get the desired behaviour when scrolling back up to the top.

The goal here is an endlessly scrollable list where when you scroll down far enough, items from the top are removed as items are added to the bottom. Vice versa, when you scroll up to the top, items from the bottom are removed as items are added to the top.

What my code is doing is loading the next set of data into the list when the user scrolls to the top, but then remains at the top as the next set of data comes back from the server. So position 0 becomes position 50 in the RecyclerView, for example, while 50 new items are inserted into the RecyclerView's data set. When done loading, the user is still looking at position 0 and sees that new items have been added, but has skipped 45+ rows of the RecyclerView without doing any additional scrolling. The user then needs to scroll down slightly and back up again to hit the scroll listener to load more items to the top of the RecyclerView.

I have "fixed" this problem by immediately calling `LinearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(50)` after the items have been added, but there is a noticeable flash on the screen as the RecyclerView jumps to this position and this prevents a smooth UX.

Any ideas?

Here's how I handle the removal and insertion of rows in the RecyclerView after the user hits the top of the screen and there are items to be loaded:

```
int end = currentList.size();
currentList.subList(currentList.size()-50, currentList.size()).clear();
recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemRangeRemoved(end-50, end);
currentList.addAll(0, items);
recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemRangeInserted(0, items.size());
layoutManager.scrollToPosition(50);
```

I'll try to help you visualize below. Each number represents a specific item in the `RecyclerView`.

State 1: 0 1 2 3 4 5

- Item 0 is at the top of screen and user has initiated the call to load more to the top of the list.

State 2: 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4

- Default behaviour without `LayoutManager.scrollToPosition(5)`: User now sees item 5 at the top of their screen, skipping items 6-0.
- Desired behaviour: User continues to see item 0 at the top of their screen but can now scroll up to view item 9, then 8, then 7...

Comment: if you want item 50 to be 0, item 51 to be 1 and so on then use java `%` operator

Comment: @pskink I don't believe that is the problem I am trying to solve. Item 0 is successfully becoming item 50, but I want the user to continue to see the same item at the top of their screen and have the ability to continue to scroll up through the newly inserted 50 items. The behaviour right now (without that final line) is jumping from item 50 to item 0 after the new items are inserted.

Comment: ok lets say you have 5 items so you would like to see 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 ... ?

Comment: I'll try to help you visualize with ID's instead.

State 1: 0 1 2 3 4 5. Item 0 is at the top of screen and user has initiated the call to load more to the top of the list.

State 2: 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4. Default behaviour: User now sees item 5 at the top of their screen, skipping items 6-0. Desired behaviour: User continues to see item 0 at the top of their screen but can now scroll up to view item 9, then 8, then 7...

Comment: @h_k Did you find any solution to this problem? Currently having the same issue... I was thinking of trying to reverse layout all the elements..